# How to parse json object and print particular value

Tags: arrays, json, go, marshalling

I have json object that consists sub object of array. how can I print particular sub object in json.
 here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //Simple Employee JSON which we will parse
    empArray := `{"meta":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mr. Boss",
            "department": "",
            "designation": "Director"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Irshad",
            "department": "IT",
            "designation": "Product Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Pankaj",
            "department": "IT",
            "designation": "Team Lead"
        }
    ]}`

    // Declared an empty interface of type Array
    var results []map[string]interface{}

    // Unmarshal or Decode the JSON to the interface.
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empArray['meta']), &results)

    fmt.Println(results)
}
```

I'm getting below error while doing soo..

```
./test.go:35:23: cannot convert empArray['\u0000'] (type byte) to type []byte
./test.go:35:33: invalid character literal (more than one character)
```

with in the `empArray` array object, I wanted to print `meta` object that consists array of employees. Please help me to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Parse the entire document and then pick out the part you want.

```
    var results map[string][]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empArray), &results)
    fmt.Println(results["meta"])
```

Comment: Thanks Bryce Donovan for your quick answer.

Comment: Please let me know how we can do the same if we have object of objects in `meta` object just like below.```{"meta":{"data":[
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Mr. Boss",
   "department": "",
   "designation": "Director"
  },
  {
   "id": 11,
   "name": "Irshad",
   "department": "IT",
   "designation": "Product Manager"
  },
  {
   "id": 12,
   "name": "Pankaj",
   "department": "IT",
   "designation": "Team Lead"
  }
 ]}}```

Comment: @ajay In my answer I provided the Go way of unmarshalling JSON objects including the new syntax you mention here.

Comment: yeah you are right. but my question is like, how can we get nested object data. here, I wanted to get `data` object that is nested by `meta`. Im trying this `var results map[string][]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(empArray), &results)
    fmt.Println(results["meta"]['data'])`. but Im getting  error 'more than one character literal'. is it correct?

Comment: Single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) are not interchangeable in Go. https://play.golang.org/p/JsQUZhZWExj shows how using `'` yields the same error. The problem is not related with parsing JSON, but with Go basics. Please follow the Go Tour: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Answer (score 2):

You should use custom structs:

```
type Employee struct {
    ID          int    `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Department  string `json:"department"`
    Designation string `json:"designation"`
}

type Employees struct {
    Meta []Employee `json:"meta"`
}
```

When you try to unmarshal the provided string into a `Employees` var it will read the annotations and know where to place each field. You can find the working example at [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ezzmiHpxAaj). I added a string representation to the `Employee` struct so that `fmt.Println` output is more redable.

In the case of having an extra nested key (`{meta: {data: [...]}}`), the types would be as follows:

```
type Employee struct {
    ID          int    `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Department  string `json:"department"`
    Designation string `json:"designation"`
}

type EmployeesData struct {
    Data []Employee `json:"data"`
}

type Employees struct {
    Meta EmployeesData `json:"meta"`
}
```

You can find the working example at [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZaQdvA-Gkss) too.

**NOTE:** I do not have context to name the structs properly, so I used `Employees` and `EmployeesData` but you should use more descriptive names that help understanding what the whole object represents and not only the meta and data fields.

Comment: Hello Adirio, thanks for your answer. but I just don't wanna create separate struct template for every object. @Bryce Donovan's answer seems somewhat relatable to me without creating struct template. I asked him a question in the comments about nested object and  please answer it if possible without creating struct templates

Comment: Hi Ajay, creating structs is how it should be done in Go. Using maps and slices of `interface{}` would require a lot of checks that are already handled by the structs themselves as they know the type. By using maps and slices of `interface{}`, it seems like you are trying to program in Go like if it was Python or JS.